# Log file reports SQL Error processing child comments

Tags: comments, mysql

I'm seeing a SQL error in my log file that reads like this:

```
[15-Oct-2016 17:34:59 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'WHERE  AND comment_parent IN (10)  ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC, comment_ID ASC' 
at line 1 for query 
SELECT wp_comments.comment_ID, wp_comments.comment_parent  
WHERE  AND comment_parent IN (10) ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC, comment_ID ASC 
made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), 
include('/themes/smb/single.php'), comments_template, 
WP_Comment_Query->__construct, WP_Comment_Query->query, 
WP_Comment_Query->get_comments, WP_Comment_Query->fill_descendants
```

The error occurs on a post that does have child comments, and our theme does show those in nested fashion, but very generically, using the wp_list_comments function.  The theme isn't using any special hooks, or any other tricks I can see.

Googling for this error, I see it show up on other people's blogs (where it is getting inserted into the output page!   At least on my site I don't see that), so I know this isn't unique to our site.

So the question is: does anybody know what produces this error, and how to fix it?

We're on Wordpress 4.6.1 and the theme is custom built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug related to caching in WordPress v4.6.1 which you can follow on [Trac ticket #37696](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37696?cversion=1&cnum_hist=5). A proper fix is scheduled for WordPress v4.6.2, but in the meantime, you could try the following workaround reported by Rarst, who created the issue on Trac:

> Issue goes away if I disable Object Cache (Siteground's Memcached).